# Error al leer string

Tags: c++, string

Estoy empezando a aprender c++ y he desarrollado el siguiente programa que me da un error al leer la variable nombre, la he puesto de tamaño 1 ya que solo quiero leer la inicial del nombre y no consigo entender porque da error, gracias de antemano.

```
string nombre[1];
string apellido1;
string apellido2;
string nombreyapellidos;

cout<<"Nombre: ";
cin>>nombre;
cout<<"ap1: ";
cin>>apellido1;
cout<<"ap2: ";
cin>>apellido2;

nombreyapellidos=apellido1+" "+apellido2+" "+nombre;
cout<<nombreyapellidos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo he puesto de tamaño 1 ya que solo quiero leer la inicial del nombre.

Ahí está tu malentendido. En C++ puedes tener formaciones<sup>1</sup> de cualquier cosa<sup>2</sup> y lo que tendrás será esa cosa repetida tantas veces como el tamaño que especifiques.

Has entendido bien que `nombre[1]` es una formación de un solo elemento, lo que no has entendido es **de qué** es la formación. Has creado una formación de un objeto `std::string`.

El objeto `std::string` se usa para guardar cadenas de caracteres, si lo que quieres es guardar una sola letra necesitas un tipo de dato que guarde una sola letra, por ejemplo `char`.

O bien lee el nombre al completo pero escribe sólo la primera letra:

```
string nombre, apellido1, apellido2;
//     ^^^^^^ <-- Cadena de caracteres, no formación

cout << "Nombre: ";
cin >> nombre;

cout << "ap1: ";
cin >> apellido1;

cout << "ap2: ";
cin >> apellido2;

string nombreyapellidos;
nombreyapellidos = apellido1 + " " + apellido2 + " " + nombre[0];
//                   Primera letra de la cadena 'nombre' --> ^^^

cout << nombreyapellidos;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>Bueno, cualquier cosa no, cualquier cosa **excepto** referencias.